# How to put QR code to pdf in wordpress with using a plugin?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, qr-code

I created a form in WordPress with Contact Form 7 and created pdf from the informations which user put there. For that I used plugin Send PDF for Contact Form 7. After submit the for it's send to email. Now I need to put to the pdf also QR code with informations from the form. Is there any plugin I can use? Or how can I do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a qr-api like [this one](http://goqr.me/api/) and just add the form data and the end of the URL.

Then just insert it "Personalize your PDF" or where ever you're adding code :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it but I don't know how to put into the url data for payment like account number etc.

Comment: I probably wrote it wrong. I need to put the qr code dynamicaly to the pdf which is generated by the plugin Send PDF for Contact Form 7.

Comment: I don't know how the plugin processes images but you can add code like this to the "Personalize your PDF" section:
`<img src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=ACCOUNT_NUMBER_HERE">`
If this doesn't work I would suggest contacting the plugin autor.

Comment: Thank you very much! I solved my problem with this.

Comment: Great :-) Remember to accept the answer for others to see the solution!